# Where can I find color settings used by Vim and NeoVim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, colorscheme, color

I've been using dotfiles created by other people to setup Vim. Recently I decided to create my own config and investigate what's NeoVim about. I'm using default OSX Terminal.app with zsh shell (I've installed oh-my-zsh). I can't figure out which colors does Vim use and why they differ from NeoVim. 
The only thing I've set so far is line number color (line 12 on screenshot).

How could I specify which colors for Vim to use? How to develop custom color scheme for Vim?

NeoVim is on the left pane on the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of NeoVim(left) and Vim]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific difference is caused by the `background` setting. It is because on a dark background, light font colors look better and vice versa. You can set it with the

```
set background=dark
```

in your vimrc.

The actual colorization rules use a relatively complex regexp-based ruleset, defined in `syntax/` directory (on most Linuxes, it is in `/usr/share/vim/vim<version>/syntax`).